# Make text area required when certain radio option is selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently developing a feedback form for my site and I am asking the user for feedback when they wish to leave the platform. The project is being developed in VueJS.
I have radio checkboxes for choosing a reason for leaving and have a text area for further details underneath. By default the text area details is not required when providing feedback but I would like to make some input there required when a user selects 'Other' as a reason for example.

I am relatively new to Vue and have experimented with v-if for conditional rendering but I couldn't find anything online about extending this logic to make the field required if a certain option was selected.

```html
<div class="eight wide field">

              <div class="ui form">
                <div class="grouped fields">
                  <label>Reason for leaving...</label>

                  <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui radio checkbox" @click="setFeedback('pricing')">
                      <input type="radio" name="example2" data-value="pricing" />
                      <label>too expensive.</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sub-field field">
                    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                      <input type="radio" name="example2" data-value="sub-option"/>
                      <label>I am moving to a cheaper platform.</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui radio checkbox" @click="setFeedback('platform_features')">
                      <input type="radio" name="example2" data-value="platform_features"/>
                      <label>missing the features I want.</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui radio checkbox" @click="setFeedback('another_platform')">
                      <input type="radio" name="example2" data-value="another_platform"/>
                      <label>I am moving to another platform.</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui radio checkbox" @click="setFeedback('no_longer_ppc')">
                      <input type="radio" name="example2" data-value="no_longer_ppc"/>
                      <label>I no longer run PPC ads.</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui radio checkbox" @click="setFeedback('no_results')">
                      <input type="radio" name="example2" data-value="no_results"/>
                      <label>I not getting any results.</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui radio checkbox" @click="setFeedback('dont_understand_ppc')">
                      <input type="radio" name="example2" data-value="dont_understand_ppc"/>
                      <label>I don't understand how to use .</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui radio checkbox" @click="setFeedback('other')">
                      <input type="radio" name="example2" data-value="other"/>
                      <label>Other (please explain further).</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>


              <textarea
                  v-model="feedback_details"
                  data-value="feedback_details"
                  class="feedback-textarea"   
              />
```

```
    sendFeedback() {
      // Establish Variables
      var self = this;

      var feedback_data = {
        feedback: self.feedback,
        feedback_details: self.feedback_details
      };

      var endpoint = window.ApiUrl + "/subscriptions/feedback";
      console.log("Endpoint: " + endpoint);

      // Send Api request and process response
      self.sendFeedbackPostRequest(endpoint, feedback_data).then(
        function(response) {
          console.log("---- Logging API Response ----");
          console.log(response);
        },
        function(error) {
          console.log("---- Logging API Error Response ----");
          console.log(error);
        }
      );

      return false;
    },

    sendFeedbackPostRequest(endpoint, postdata) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Define Self
        var self = this;
        // Sending Api Request
        self.$http
          .post(endpoint, postdata)
          .then(
            function(response) {
              resolve(response);
            },
            function(error) {
              reject(error);
            }
          )
          .finally(function() {
            console.log("Run account deletion here...");
            // self.deleteAccount();
          });
      });
    }
  }
};
```

I would wish for the textarea to be required when 'Other' is selected as the user's feedback option.

Comment: You will have to add this logic to the method that is submitting this form. Can you show this logic?

Comment: Added the submit method

Answer (score 0):

Just use `v-bind` or the `:` shorthand for the `readonly` attribute, e.g.

```
<textarea
    v-model="feedback_details"
    data-value="feedback_details"
    class="feedback-textarea"
    v-bind:required="shouldTextareaBeRequired"
/>
```

Then, the computed property `shouldTextareaBeRequired` can return a boolean based on the value set by `setFeedback()` method: if "Other" is the value, then return `true`, otherwise return `false`. From your question it is unclear how you are storing user feedback, but it is probably stored as part of the component's data somewhere.

Comment: Wouldn't that then mean that selecting another option for example wouldn't let the user write in this field? I'd like any user irregardless of choice to have the option to write further details if they wish, but to only make it mandatory for people that select 'Other', sorry if I didn't make that as clear as I could've.

Comment: @NathanThomas Sorry, my bad. Then you just use `v-bind:required`